# String Structure in C

Tags: c, string

I know this will sound stupid, etc... but I'm sort of desperate. I'm a C++/Objective-C/Python guy and I'm used to the convenience & neatness provided by String class or NSString Class or Python's sweet strings. But I'm doing few assignments and our prof is just way too keen on using C. I don't have an issue with C character strings but I not super excited to use them.

So I thought of writing a String data structure first (maybe a struct containing a pointer to hold characters) and accompanying functions. But before I delve into it, I was wondering if there is any open source content available for something similar... and if you guys/girls can please tell me about it. It would be a big help. Thanks :)

Comment: You said it: Python strings.

Comment: If your educator wants you to write in C, you'd better learn to write in C. They're unlikely to be pleased about having to wade through bucketloads of string class code to see if you've done the job. And this will be good training for the workforce where, though you can _suggest_ improvements, the person who pays the bills makes the decisions :-)

Comment: yeah... I'm still gonna write in C... but just sort of want a wrapper around the ugly syntax. I know how to work with C strings... I'm not learning anything new with this... just wasting my time :(

Comment: @BasicWolf Python Strings... are you suggesting me to use some sort of interface (something like Swig) so that I may be able to use Python strings from C?

Comment: Wrappers aroung "ugly" C syntax produces monstrosities like `#define begin {`. If you have to learn C, learn it in all its glory. _Especially_ when your educator has mandated it. NUDGE NUDGE WINK WINK !!!

Comment: CPython (the de-facto standard implementation of Python) is written in C. Thus, you have a complete source of a "String structure" there.

Comment: okay... I'm making a web server... so its about using socket programming and more about how to handle threading with multiple requests etc etc... not how to use C strings... please stop supporting my "alleged" educator :D

Comment: C std library for C strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a better string library in C, maybe you should look at [The Better String Library](http://bstring.sf.net/).  It provides a sensible interface that is considerably improved over raw C strings and the standard C library functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cant write member functions to a struct in C. So what you can do will in all likeliness be only marginally better than `char*` + `strlen` etc. If at all.

If you just want to hide the `*`, you can just do

```
typedef char* MyString;
```

---

Edit: Take a look at [Coping with Character Strings in C](http://www.idinews.com/string.html) looks to be talking about the exact same issue.

Comment: yes I know... don't worry about what I'll achieve out of it... if it will save me to look at that hideous syntax... then I'm all for it.

Comment: @shobhu if the `*` is your definition of ugly syntax, you can easily do `typedef char* MyString;`

Comment: no its not pointer... its in the way we allocate, its in the way we use strtok to parse... that it hasn't got an elegant way to get the residual part after parsing, its in the way that I've to take care of '\0' character if sending it in a stream... say in socket programming, its in the way that I've to use ** when I want a list of strings... etc etc.

Comment: @shobhu take a look at [Coping with Character Strings in C](http://www.idinews.com/string.html) and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would think of simple way to make it.

```
typedef struct __my_string {
    char   data[MAX_CHAR]; // or even, char *data;
} MyString;
```

Comment: Oh wow! `MAX_CHAR`? What happens when I need a string longer than `MAX_CHAR`?

Comment: oh I can set MAX_CHAR to some ridiculous number... I'm not looking for memory management right now